# time for iOS App downloads to appear in iTunes connect

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

I just released my first app.. How long does it take for the downloads to appear in iTunes Connect? I have download the App as well as a couple more people. It has been about 2-3 hours... But I am not seeing any downloads in iTunes Connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first off, this question has been asked several times already and is often answered anywhere else on the net. I would recommend to do some research before asking.

Now, to your question:

The stats are updated at 12:00 am / 24:00 PST (Pacific Standard Time, based on Apple's location in the Silicon Valley) each day.

Hope that clears your questions :)